# How can I get Vim to detect the filetype and do syntax highlighting for a new file right after pasting in its first buffer

Tags: vim

I often copy text from a file, or from a web page that is formatted as html, or json or python.  To work with it, I open an empty Vim buffer and paste it in (with ctrl-v).  At that point I can manually set the syntax or use :filetype detect, but I'd like it to happen automatically, like when opening a file.

I tried some autocmds, but I don't know if the syntax was off, but they didn't work.  I tried

```
au TextChangedI * :filetype detect
```

but it had no effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a single mapping that does everything:

```
" the function where everything happens
function! MagicPaste()
    " create a new buffer, see :help :enew
    enew

    " grab the content of register "+
    let reg = getreg("+", 1, 1)

    " figure out how many empty lines there are at the top
    " and remove them, if any
    let i = 0
    while reg[i] == ""
        let i += 1
    endwhile
    if i > 0
        call remove(reg, 0, i - 1)
    endif

    " insert the the remaining lines in the buffer,
    " see :help setline() and :help getreg()
    call setline(1, reg)

    " perform filetype detection
    filetype detect
endfunction

" the custom mapping
nnoremap <key> <Cmd>call MagicPaste()<CR>
```

Note that this snippet assumes that you have a proper Vim, built with clipboard support.

Comment: Thank you - this looks like it will do what I want!  However, I couldn't get it to work so far.  I've never worked with functions in vim.  I don't know how to debug them.  I put your code as is into my _vimrc and used <c-b> as the mapped key.   To test it I copied some html, opened a new gvim instance, and entered ctrl-b.  The text was copied in, but it doesn't appear the "filetype detect" was executed as the syntax was still empty and the highlighting didn't change.  How do I debug this?

Comment: I'm not sure. I tested this with HTML, actually, before submitting it, and it worked nicely: https://i.imgur.com/HUnr9vX.png.

Comment: Hmm, it seems to be an issue with ":filetype detect". I tried it with different html, and it did work!  The one that didn't work had an empty line at the top.  Running ":filetype detect" didn't do anything until I removed that line, and then it worked.  Now I need to add something that will delete empty lines at the top before running "filetype detect"

Comment: OK, I added this line and it seems to work:<br>

    " remove any blank lines at the top<br>
    1s/\n*//

Comment: @AnthonyAlbert FWIW, I updated the answer with that corner case in mind.